# Thread-private lists in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Thread sub-class called XmlProcessor that needs to accept some list or array of Strings to process.  I need this list to be completely private to each thread, so that it isn't modified in any way by other threads.  What is my best option?

Thanks,
Jared

Comment: Vivien Barousse has a great idea. Why it may not have worked is you may need to override the initialValue method of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Jareds comment it seems you have something that looks like this.

```
public class MyClass extends Runnable{
   static ThreadLocal<List<String>> listBonds = new ThreadLocal<List<String>>();

   public MyClass (List<String> list){
        listBonds.set(list);
   }
   public void run(){
      listBonds.get(); // it returns null here?
   }

}
```

If my assumption is true then the reason listBonds.get() is null is because a different thread is accessing listBonds when you invoke `set` to when you invoke `get`

Image this

```
Thread 1:
  Thread myClass = new Thread(new MyClass(someList));
    listBonds.set(someList);
  myClass.start(); 
Thread 2: (MyClass)
  listBonds.get() --- A new thread is requesting the threadlocal variable and hence its null
```

If this is the case then the Runnable instance will be inherently thread-local/thread-safe and then you can have the List be an instance variable of the Runnable

Comment: I think John V. is right. Remember that the executing thread in the constructor is different than the thread in the run method. The constructor is the launching thread. Run is the newly created thread.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand correctly:
XmlProcessor has a private List<String> member, and my main thread calls new XmlProcessor(listOne).start(); Then it calls new XmlProcessor(listTwo).start();  Will the first XmlProcessor thread still reference listOne, or will all XmlProcessor threads now reference listTwo?

Comment: @Jared.  If listOne and listTwo are instance fields of their respective XmProcessor thread's then neither the first thread nor the second thread will see one another's List.  Each thread will be pointing to different Lists

Answer (score 5):

Use [the ThreadLocal class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html). It allows you to create references visible only by the current thread.

Comment: I tried this, but perhaps I did something wrong.  In the class definition I declared:

    private static ThreadLocal<List<String>> listBonds = new ThreadLocal<List<String>>();

Then in the constructor (which takes List<String> list as a parameter), I did: listBonds.set(list);

But in the run() method of the thread, if I do List<String> list = listBonds.get();, list is null.

Comment: Be aware, if you pass the list into "set", the list will not be thread-safe since the calling thread could still have a reference to the list.

Answer (score 2):

If there is an instance of XmlProcessor per thread and the list is held as a private, it should be accessible from other threads so long as you:
1. don't provider a getter or setter method
2. ensure that the reference held by the instance is a copy of whatever was passed rather than just a pointer to the list that might be held by other objects.

You might consider using Guava's ImmutableList class to enforce this if the list cannot be changed.

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release09/javadoc/index.html